# Symfony2 - Twig form vars not working as expected

Tags: php, symfony, twig

**SOLVED**

So I found another thread [on stackoverflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149954/key-datei-for-array-with-keys-does-not-exist-while-dump-says-it-does), and one of the answers worked.  Using the following code does work for some reason!

```
<pre>{{ dump(form.parent.parent.parent.vars[form.parent.type.vars.value ~ '_choices']|default('')) }}</pre>
```

**ORIGINAL POST**

I am hoping you can assist me with a headscratcher.  Any guidance you all can offer would be greatly appreciated.

I can do the following code:

```
<pre>{{ dump(form.parent.parent.parent.vars) }}</pre>
```

When I run that code, I get a breakdown of the array.  A shortened version is below.

```
array (size=28)
  'page_choices' => 
    array (size=2)
      1 => string 'Test Page 1' (length=11)
      2 => string 'Test Page 2' (length=11)
  'file_choices' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

Now, I also do the following and get "page_choices" as expected.

```
<pre>{{ dump(form.parent.type.vars.value ~ '_choices') }}</pre>
```

The problem comes when I put it all together:

```
<pre>{{ dump(form.parent.parent.parent.vars[form.parent.type.vars.value ~ '_choices']) }}</pre>
```

When I try to put the code together in order to get the data from the "page_choices" array key, I get the following error:

> Key "_choices" for array with keys "value, attr, form, id, name,
>   full_name, disabled, label, multipart, block_prefixes,
>   unique_block_prefix, translation_domain, cache_key, read_only, errors,
>   valid, data, required, max_length, pattern, size, label_attr,
>   compound, method, action, submitted, page_choices, file_choices" does
>   not exist

It even lists "page_choices" as a key.  I am not sure why both parts dump as expected, but when I combine them, it's like it only gets the "_choices" for the key.  I cannot figure out why they work apart but not together.

**EDIT**

Both of the following blocks also return as "true", which is even more confusing to me.

```
<pre>{{ form.parent.type.vars.value ~ '_choices' in form.parent.parent.parent.vars|keys ? "True" : "False" }}</pre>

<pre>{{ form.parent.parent.parent.vars[form.parent.type.vars.value ~ '_choices'] is defined ? "True" : "False" }}</pre>
```

Comment: What about `{{ dump(attribute(form.parent.parent.parent.vars, form.parent.type.vars.value ~ '_choices')) }}`? Did you try `{{ dump(form.parent.parent.parent.vars['page_choices']) }}` too? (I expect that one to work, but want to make sure.) Finally, what about `{% set temp = form.parent.type.vars.value ~ '_choices' %}` and then `{{ dump(form.parent.parent.parent.vars[temp]) }}`?

Comment: I would try sjagr 's reply. My advice is that whenever you are trying to do something that large like form.parent.parent.parent.vars[form.parent.type.vars.value ~ '_choices']  probably it's not the way to go, and should be a simpler way to achieve what you want, I would do my best to keep the Twig front-end as clean as possible and not over-complicate things.

Comment: @sjagr When I manually type "page_choices" as the key per your suggestion, I do in fact get the data I'm looking for.  When I try your first comment of separating the vars by a comma, it results in the same error.  I also tried the twig set way in order to store the value as a variable, but the same error persists.

Comment: @MartinRios I am doing this because I am creating a tool to create items on a menu, which can be an external link, a link to an internal file, or a link to an internal custom page.  Based on the "type" dropdown box they change, I am trying to change the "link" box to a select or text box as needed.  I am unsure if there is a better approach, but this seems like it should work for what I'm trying to do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I had to add |default('') after my code in order to get it working correctly.  I'm not sure why, but the following code ended up working!

```
<pre>{{ dump(form.parent.parent.parent.vars[form.parent.type.vars.value ~ '_choices']|default('')) }}</pre>
```

Thank you everyone for trying to figure this out with me!